# Mysql statement not returning correct data

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to put together an MySql query that will return results based on values passed from php. However, the code I am using is throwing an error of 'unknown column in' and then the name of the value in the var $query1. I have obviously gone wrong somewhere and would appreciate some guidance as to correct the error.

I have posted only the relevant code, but would happy to post more if required. Just need to check the error in my statement.

Many thanks.

```
$searchSql = ($qtype != '' && $query != '' && $query1 != '') ? "WHERE ".$qtype." LIKE '%".$query."%' AND customer = ".$query1."" : '';
```

Comment: You may need a space before the "WHERE"

Comment: You mean before the " or after. Thanks

Comment: Change your `$searchSql` to `$searchSql = ($qtype != '' && $query != '' && $query1 != '') ? " WHERE $qtype LIKE '%$query%' AND customer = $query1" : '';` for readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could possibly be due to a missing single-quote around your second criteria:

```
AND customer = ".$query1.""
```

Should potentially be:

```
AND customer = '".$query1."'"
```

If $query1 is text.

Comment: That was it. many thanks. It says I can accept in 9 mins. Will upvote then.